# How are the sign and overflow flags used in x86-64 assembly language to determine "less than" in CMOVL and CMOVNG?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am reading [AMD64 Architecture Programmer's Manual Volume 1: Application Programming][1]. On page 47, which is about CMOVcc, it has a table which states:

```
CMOVL
CMOVNGE SF <> OF Conditional move if less
Conditional move if not greater or equal
```

First, I'm not sure exactly what `<>` means here. But I am guessing that it means "sign flag is opposite of overflow flag." So part one of my question is, "am I right?"

But my main question is, **how is it determined that the definition of "less than" can be represented by the condition of these 2 flags?** For example, after learning standard math in school, my brain essentially performs the following in the way described:

```
mov rax, 15
mov rbx, 50
cmp rbx, rax
```

I simply "see" that 50 is a number with greater value than 15 and instantly know that 50 is the greater number. I know this likely because the greater number has more digits, no `.` and no `-` in front of it.

However, from what I gather by what I've learned so far, the CPU can't "see" this, but instead, it performs a subtraction operation and then uses the resulting flags to "know" which number is greater and which is less.

Could someone explain how these rules regarding the sign flag and overflow flag can definitively tell me that one quantity is less than another?
[1]: https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/24592.pdf

Comment: <> means ≠ (as you guessed)

Comment: You can just work out the cases on a simple example of, say, a 4-bit register. (If the subtraction didn't underflow, then the sign of the result tells you whether you subtracted a larger number from a smaller one. If the subtraction did underflow, then the sign is backwards due to the underflow.)

Comment: Intel's pseudo-code uses `SF≠ OF` - https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmovcc.  The instructions of course work identically for both vendors, so it can be a good idea to check the other vendor if you aren't sure you understand their notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider each case:

```
  A    B    A - B    <    S    V    
 127   1     126     F    0    0    
  1   127   -126     T    1    0
 127   -1   -128     F    1    1
-127   1    -128     T    1    0
-127   2     127     T    0    1
```

Comment: My confusion lies in that according to http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt "Overflow can only happen when adding two numbers of the same sign and
getting a different sign.  So, to detect overflow we don't care about
any bits except the sign bits.  Ignore the other bits." But in your example you add 127 + -1 but the overflow flag is set. Maybe the question is, what's the difference between subtracting 127 -1 and adding 127 + (-1)?

Comment: Your question was about `cmp`, which is a subtraction operation, and that is what is shown in the table. There’s no addition here, so there’s no “add 127 + -1” in the table. The first row is “127 - 1” and it doesn’t set overflow.

Comment: sorry I quoted the wrong part in comment above... I meant to quote the subtraction part, but I understand now and it actually makes sense.